# KVO When View Dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently have a main web view (`UIViewController`) that presents a `UIViewController` like this:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am trying to observe when the presented view controller gets dismissed using:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have tried observing a variable in the main web view that the presented view sets when it's being dismissed, but that doesn't seem to work.

How would I go about observing when the presented view gets dismissed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain "that doesn't seem to work".

Comment: Post your code where you are registering as an observer and the code that handles the change.

Comment: Got it working using NSNotificationCenter! Thanks anywho.

Comment: @Pat how did you get it working? Mind posting an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put some code in the **viewWillDisappear** method?  You're not clear on why you actually want to observe the variable.  However this method will be called just before the view moves off.  Conversely you can run code in the **viewDidDisappear** which is run after the view pops.